# highchart- how do I hide y-axis, when y-axis is set with max and min limits

Tags: highcharts

I am working with highcharts and I have to set min and max limits on y-axis but when I try to hide the series by clicking on legends y-axis does not disappear as shown in the snippet. Temperature y-axis does not hide when its corresponding series get disappeared on clicking legend. Issue is that in the code 
  showEmpty for y-axis is set to false which make the other axis without the max and min values dissaper on click. I tried to find out the solution in Highchart documentation but have not found anything usefull in regard to my issue,

```js
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            }],
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +'°C';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true,
                showEmpty: false,
                max: 100,
                min:0,
    
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mm';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                showEmpty: false
    
            }, { // Tertiary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mb';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true,
                showEmpty: false
            }],
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var unit = {
                        'Rainfall': 'mm',
                        'Temperature': '°C',
                        'Sea-Level Pressure': 'mb'
                    }[this.series.name];
    
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' '+ unit;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                x: 120,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 80,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Rainfall',
                color: '#4572A7',
                type: 'column',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    
            }, {
                name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#AA4643',
                yAxis: 2,
                data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dashStyle: 'shortdot'
    
            }, {
                name: 'Temperature',
                color: '#89A54E',
                type: 'spline',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }]
        });
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this issue if you use [`softMin`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.softMin) and [`softMax`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.softMax) instead of `min` and `max`.

```js
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            }],
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +'°C';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true,
                showEmpty: false,
                softMax: 100,
                softMin:0,
    
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mm';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                showEmpty: false
    
            }, { // Tertiary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mb';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true,
                showEmpty: false
            }],
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var unit = {
                        'Rainfall': 'mm',
                        'Temperature': '°C',
                        'Sea-Level Pressure': 'mb'
                    }[this.series.name];
    
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' '+ unit;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                x: 120,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 80,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Rainfall',
                color: '#4572A7',
                type: 'column',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    
            }, {
                name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#AA4643',
                yAxis: 2,
                data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dashStyle: 'shortdot'
    
            }, {
                name: 'Temperature',
                color: '#89A54E',
                type: 'spline',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }]
        });
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```